# Instantiate a class variable from a method - Java

Tags: java, design-patterns

I know there is not a good idea to instantiate a class variable from a method but unfortunately, I face a situation where I do not have any other solution. I have created some custom validators
 and I have an object (`rawField`) that is populated with some information from GUI. To populate that instance variable I use the method validate from `javax.faces.Validator`.

So I get the information for each field from GUI through this event.

My question is: Is this a good design pattern? Has anybody a better idea about how should I instantiate this variable?

Parent class:

```
 public abstract class FormFieldValidator extends BaseValidator implements IFormFieldValidator, Validator {

            protected RawField rawField;

            @Override
            public abstract RawField doInitialize(Object inputObject);

            @Override
            public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {

            rawField = doInitialize(value);

            if (rawField == null) {

                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The field cannot be empty");

            }

            doBasicValidation();
            }
    }
```

Child class

```
@FacesValidator(Constants.Validators.USERNAME_VALIDATOR)

public class UsernameValidator extends FormFieldValidator {

    @Override
    public RawField doInitialize(Object guiField) {

    ValidationConditions validationConditions = new ValidationConditions

        .Builder(Entities.ParamsSize.USERNAME_MIN_LENGTH, Entities.ParamsSize.USERNAME_MAX_LENGTH)

            .setRegex(Constants.Regex.USERNAME_REGEX).setNullable(false).setUnique(true).build();


    FieldDetails fieldDetails = new FieldDetails(guiField, "Username");

    RawField rawField = new RawField(fieldDetails, validationConditions);

    return rawField;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessarily an antipattern to populate an object with data on method invocation. What's not right in your code is that the method `validate`, that does more that validation. First it initializes the variable, then it validates the object. It would be better to call it something like `populateAndValidate` or remove the `doInitialize` from the body and make sure it's invoked by the client code. Null-check of `rawField` field can be a part of validation process.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you mean when you say that doInitialize must be invoked by the "client code"?